# 3 column form with 3rd column spanning vertically

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to find a way to have a form that displays the fields horizontally rather than vertically....with the exception of the last column.  I'd like that to span vertically.  Here's the code I have for getting the 2 columns the way I'd like them:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .display-label, .editor-label
        {
            margin: 1em 0 0 0;
            display: block;
            width: 300px;
        }

        .display-field, .editor-field
        {
            margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
            display: block;
            width: 300px;
        }

        .sameline-wrapper
        {
            float: left;
            display: inline;
        }

        .newline
        {
            display: block;
            clear: both;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="test.html" method="post">
        <div class="newline">
            <div class="sameline-wrapper">
                <div class="display-label">
                    Here is a field:
                </div>
                <div class="display-field">
                    <input type="text" id="t1" style="width: 100px;" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="sameline-wrapper">
                <div class="display-label">
                    Here is a second field:
                </div>
                <div class="display-field">
                    <input type="text" id="t2" style="width: 100px;" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="newline">
            <div class="sameline-wrapper">
                <div class="display-label">
                    Here is a third field:
                </div>
                <div class="display-field">
                    <input type="text" id="t3" style="width: 100px;" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="sameline-wrapper">
                <div class="display-label">
                    Here is a fourth field:
                </div>
                <div class="display-field">
                    <input type="text" id="t4" style="width: 100px;" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="newline">
            <div class="sameline-wrapper">
                <div class="display-label">
                    Here is a fifth field:
                </div>
                <div class="display-field">
                    <input type="text" id="Text1" style="width: 100px;" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="sameline-wrapper">
                <div class="display-label">
                    Here is a sixth field:
                </div>
                <div class="display-field">
                    <input type="text" id="Text2" style="width: 100px;" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="newline">
            <div class="sameline-wrapper">
                <div class="display-label">
                    Here is a seventh field:
                </div>
                <div class="display-field">
                    <input type="text" id="Text3" style="width: 100px;" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="sameline-wrapper">
                <div class="display-label">
                    Here is a eigth field:
                </div>
                <div class="display-field">
                    <input type="text" id="Text4" style="width: 100px;" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish now is to have a 3rd column to the left that spans the entire height of the other rows.  The idea is to have a textarea control in there and it all look uniform.  I've added this image to help see what I'm trying to do:
[image: Form Image]

and here's a fiddle:
[3 Column Form](http://jsfiddle.net/robertfah/Ea54y/)

I just don't know how to get that 3rd column to line up to the left of the others and to be the same height (vertically) as the other rows.  Any help is greatly appreicated!

Comment: I only see one column in your JSFiddle.

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales Really?  That's odd...I've been working on it but I didn't remove any columns....try this link: http://jsfiddle.net/robertfah/Ea54y/2/

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales - it may be because your panes in jsfiddle aren't wide enough.  I just moved my output pane to the right and noticed it made it look like it was one column.  Try moving the splitter to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rearrange your html to specify one div for each column like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .newspaperCol
        {
            float: left;
            width: 33%;
        }

        .display-label
        {
            margin: 1em 0 0 0;
            display: block;
        }

        .display-field
        {
            margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="newspaperCol">
        <label class="display-label">Field 1:</label>
        <input class="display-field" type="text" id="text1">
        <br />
        <label class="display-label">Field 3:</label>
        <input class="display-field" type="text" id="text3">
        <br />
        <label class="display-label">Field 5:</label>
        <input class="display-field" type="text" id="text5">
        <br />
        <label class="display-label">Field 7:</label>
        <input class="display-field" type="text" id="text7">
    </div>
    <div class="newspaperCol">
        <label class="display-label">Field 2:</label>
        <input class="display-field" type="text" id="text2">
        <br />
        <label class="display-label">Field 4:</label>
        <input class="display-field" type="text" id="text4">
        <br />
        <label class="display-label">Field 6:</label>
        <input class="display-field" type="text" id="text6">
        <br />
        <label class="display-label">Field 8:</label>
        <input class="display-field" type="text" id="text8">
    </div>
    <div class="newspaperCol">
        <label class="display-label">Notes:</label>
        <textarea rows="17" cols="30" id="notestext"></textarea>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**
I re-read your question and updated my answer using more of your original code. I think you're missing some HTML for the notes elements. Try adding the colLeft and colRight css classes and the associated "div" elements shown below.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .colLeft
        {
            float: left;
            width: 66%;
        }

        .colRight
        {
            float: left;
            width: 33%;
        }

        .display-label, .editor-label
        {
            margin: 1em 0 0 0;
            display: block;
            width: 300px;
        }

        .display-field, .editor-field
        {
            margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
            display: block;
            width: 300px;
        }

        .sameline-wrapper
        {
            float: left;
            display: inline;
        }

        .newline
        {
            display: block;
            clear: both;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="test.html" method="post">
    <div class="colLeft">
        <div class="newline">
            <div class="sameline-wrapper">
                <div class="display-label">
                    Here is a field:
                </div>
                <div class="display-field">
                    <input type="text" id="t1" style="width: 100px;" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="sameline-wrapper">
                <div class="display-label">
                    Here is a second field:
                </div>
                <div class="display-field">
                    <input type="text" id="t2" style="width: 100px;" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="newline">
            <div class="sameline-wrapper">
                <div class="display-label">
                    Here is a third field:
                </div>
                <div class="display-field">
                    <input type="text" id="t3" style="width: 100px;" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="sameline-wrapper">
                <div class="display-label">
                    Here is a fourth field:
                </div>
                <div class="display-field">
                    <input type="text" id="t4" style="width: 100px;" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="newline">
            <div class="sameline-wrapper">
                <div class="display-label">
                    Here is a fifth field:
                </div>
                <div class="display-field">
                    <input type="text" id="Text1" style="width: 100px;" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="sameline-wrapper">
                <div class="display-label">
                    Here is a sixth field:
                </div>
                <div class="display-field">
                    <input type="text" id="Text2" style="width: 100px;" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="newline">
            <div class="sameline-wrapper">
                <div class="display-label">
                    Here is a seventh field:
                </div>
                <div class="display-field">
                    <input type="text" id="Text3" style="width: 100px;" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="sameline-wrapper">
                <div class="display-label">
                    Here is a eigth field:
                </div>
                <div class="display-field">
                    <input type="text" id="Text4" style="width: 100px;" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="colRight">
        <label>Notes:</label>
        <textarea rows="15" cols="30" id="notestext"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked great.  You're right, I left out the html for the Notes field because what I had wasn't working and I didn't want to confuse anyone as to the desired location of the Notes field.